# using not with sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have been asked to display results in my sql server database for the following question

> What software packages are not installed on any HP computers?
>   I have tried the following but I am still getting results for the PACKNAME Manta but that package is installed on an HP computer. What am I missing?

```
select * from package where PACK in
  ( select PACK from software where TAGNUM in 
   ( select tagnum from PC where comp NOT in
     ( select comp from computer where MFRNAME = 'HP')))
```

I have attached an image of the data for your reference below

[image]

Comment: this looks like some sort of `homework`. Before we attempt to help you with the query, Is there any particular method of query that you must use or cannot use ?

Comment: I have been told to only use sub-queries.

Comment: Any query that answers a question "where something doesnt exist" is generally best answered with a NOT EXISTS(subquery) pattern. Makes it really easy to understand and generally efficient to run. I would research that.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: This is for Microsoft SQL server management studio 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery that joins the other tables together, and contains your filter condition:

```
select
pk.pack,
pk.packname,
pk.packv,
pk.packtype,
pk.packcost
from package pk
where not exists (
                    select 1
                    from software s
                    inner join pc on pc.tagnum = s.tagnum
                    inner join computer c on c.comp = pc.comp
                    where s.pack = pk.pack
                    and c.mfrname = 'HP'
                 )
order by pk.pack;
```

**Result**

```
| pack |         packname | packv |        packtype | packcost |
|------|------------------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| AC11 | Quick Accounting |   4.1 |      Accounting |   754.95 |
| AC12 |   Accounting MIS |   4.0 |      Accounting |     2000 |
| AC13 |        Quickbook |  2005 |      Accounting |      300 |
| DB11 |            Manta |   1.5 |        Database |      380 |
| DB13 |       SQL Server |  2005 |        Database |      500 |
| DB14 |           My SQL |  2005 |        Database |      300 |
| SS11 |          Easycal |   5.5 |     Spreadsheet |   225.15 |
| WP04 |       Word Power |     2 | Word Processing |      118 |
| WP07 |        Good Word |   3.2 | Word Processing |       35 |
| WP14 |           GOOGLE |     2 | Word Processing |      118 |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f687/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with installed as
( select PACK from software where TAGNUM in ( select tagnum from PC where comp in ( select comp from computer where MFRNAME = 'HP')))
select * from Package p left join installed i on p.pack = i.pack
where i.pack is null
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I am still receiving a result with PACKNAME MANTA in the list.

Comment: It must be in the list then.  have you checked?

Comment: Yes. Manta is installed on the HP computer associated with the  PACK DB22 but the question is phrased in a way that it is looking for all packages that are not installed on any HP computers